# Program written in generated code based on unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, code-generation

As I was doing test driven development I pondered whether a hypothetical program could be completely developed by generated code based on tests. i.e. is there an ability to have a generator that creates the code specifically to pass tests. Would the future of programming languages just be to write tests?

Comment: I don't think this question is specific enough for anyone to provide a reasonable answer, unfortunately, unless there is an existing system that allows one to do this already.

Comment: You basically described machine learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this would be a tough one as, at least for the initial generations of such technology, developers would be very skeptical of generated code's correctness. So human review would have to be involved as well.

As a simple illustration of what I mean, suppose you write 10 tests for a function, with sample inputs and expected outputs covering every scenario you can think of. A program could trivially generate code which passed all of these tests with nothing more than a rudimentary  switch statement (your ten inputs matched to their expected outputs). This code would obviously not be *correct*, but it would take a human to see that.

That's just a simple example. It isn't hard to imagine more sophisticated programs which might not generate a switch statement but still produce solutions that aren't actually correct, and which could be wrong in much more subtle ways. Hence my suggestion that any technology along these lines would be met with a deep level of skepticism, at least at first.

Comment: Why would that code not be correct? You could use variables in your tests and define the desired value of a function for an entire interval of the functions domain, then the switch statement would just use your expression for the desired output, using those variables.

Comment: "define the desired value of a function for an entire interval of the functions domain" That's called implementing the function!

Comment: Yes, I realized this too. There ought to be tools to support test driven development, by going from concrete tets cases to more abstract test cases to entirely abstract function definitions.

Answer (score 1):

If code can be generated completely, then the basis of the generator would have to be a specification that exactly describes the code. This generator would then be something like a compiler that cross compiles one language into an other.

Tests are not such a language. They only assert that a specific aspect of the code functionality is valid and unchanged. By doing so they scaffold the code so that it does not break, even when it is refactored.

But how would I compare these two ways of development?

1) If the generator works correctly, then the specification is always transferred into correct code. I postulate that this code is tested by design and needs no additional test. Better TDD the generator than the generated code.

2) Whether you have a specification that leads to generated code or  specifications expressed as tests that ensure that code works is quite equivalent in my eyes.

3) You can combine both ways of development. Generate a program framework with a tested generator from a specification and then enrich the generated code by using TDD. Attention: You then have two different development cycles running in one project. That means, you have to ensure that you always can regenerate the generated code when specifications change und that your additional code still correctly fits into the generated code.

Just one small example: Imagine a tool that can generate code from an UML class diagram. This could be done in an way that you can develop the methods with TDD, but the structure of the classes is defined in UML and you would not need to test this again.

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible sometime in the future, simple tests can be used to generate code:

```
assertEquals(someclass.get_value(), true)
```

but getting the correct output from a black-box integration test is what I would guess is an NP-complete problem:

```
assertEquals(someclass.do_something(1), file_content(/some/file))

assertEquals(someclass.do_something(2), file_content(/some/file))
assertEquals(someclass.do_something(2), file_content(/some/file2))

assertEquals(someclass.do_something(3), file_content(/some/file2))
```

Does this mean that the resulting code will always write to /some/file? Does it mean that the resulting code should always write to /some/file2? Either could be true. What if it needs to only do the minimal set to get the tests to pass? Without knowing the context and writing very exact and bounding tests, no code could figure out (at this point in time) what the test author intended.